# filling missing data with other than mean values

Tags: machine-learning, mean, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

What all options are available for filling missing data ?

One obvious choice is the mean, but if the percentage of missing data is large, it will decrease the accuracy.

So how do we deal with missing values if they are in great number ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [tag:data-imputation] and [tag:multiple-imputation] tags?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8322/filling-missing-data-with-other-than-mean-values.